# using SYSTEMTIME to change Date and Time in 24 mode

Tags: c#, windows, sysdatetime

I use SYSTEMTIME struct to change my system datetime like follows:

```
 [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
 public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
     st.wYear = 2009;
     st.wMonth = 1;
     st.wDay = 1;
     st.wHour = 23;
     st.wMinute = 1;
     st.wSecond = 1;
     SetSystemTime(ref st);
 }
```

the Date was changed, but the Time is not effected
I want to change my system date and time in 24 mode.
can you help me about that ?

Comment: Could you show your SYSTEMTIME structure definition? Did you just grab it from pinvoke.net?

Comment: What's the return value of `SetSystemTime`?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce this. With a very simple console application below, I can *either* get it to do nothing at all (running normally, with no elevated privileges) *or* I can change both date and time (running it as an administrator). It never changed just the date. However, that's on Windows 7, with UAC enabled. Perhaps you're running on a different version, or with different access controls? I strongly suspect this is an access control issue.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct SYSTEMTIME
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Year;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Month;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short DayOfWeek;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Day;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Hour;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Minute;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Second;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U2)] public short Milliseconds;
}

class Test
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    public extern static uint SetSystemTime(ref SYSTEMTIME lpSystemTime);

    static void Main()
    {
        SYSTEMTIME st = new SYSTEMTIME();
        st.Year = 2009;
        st.Month = 1;
        st.Day = 1;
        st.Hour = 23;
        st.Minute = 1;
        st.Second = 1;
        SetSystemTime(ref st);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[SYSTEMTIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should look like this:

```
typedef struct _SYSTEMTIME {
  WORD wYear;
  WORD wMonth;
  WORD wDayOfWeek;
  WORD wDay;
  WORD wHour;
  WORD wMinute;
  WORD wSecond;
  WORD wMilliseconds;
} SYSTEMTIME, *PSYSTEMTIME;
```

[SetSystemTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should return true on success.

And time is set in 24hr format.

**wYear: 1601-30827**

**wMonth: 1-12**

**wDayOfWeek: 0-6**

**wDay: 1-31**

**wHour: 0-23**

**wMinute: 0-59**

**wSecond: 0-59**

**wMilliseconds: 0-999**